# Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8: TDD aborts environment

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tdd

I have installed Visual Studio Express for Windows 8 on my development system. When I add a project for TDD and build the solution, the IDE crashes -- apparently it is unable to find any tests (even though they are there in code). The "Test Output" window indicates that it is searching for tests, and then the entire devenv crashes.

This was working correctly using the trial version of Visual Studio 2012 Professional, but since uninstalling that and replacing it with VS Express for Win8 I have had no luck in getting MSTest to work without crashing the environment.

Any ideas as to what I might be missing?

Comment: It will be better to report a bug on https://connect.microsoft.com/ for Visual Studio. Also you can try to do Repair for your installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a collision with another process on the computer (Garmin update program). With this process stopped, Test Output works as expected. The problem was fixed in VS2013.